# LibreOffice - split words automatically at certain position

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-writer

I have a text document with words that I automatically extracted from another text document. It contains names of species and looks like this (one long string of words):

```
Tenagomysis tasmaniaeAnisomysis mixta australisParamesopodopsis rufaCyathura carinata
```

I would like to have every species name in a separate line, so it looks like this:

```
Tenagomysis tasmaniae
Anisomysis mixta australis
Paramesopodopsis rufa
Cyathura carinata
```

So manually I would have to hit enter before every capital letter. Is there any way to make this an automatic proccess, to split words according to a certain characteristic within it (formatting, capital letter, etc.)?

In the end I want to obtain a spreadsheet with one species name in a single row so any other way to do this is also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it.

Use the "Find & Replace..." (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) in LibreOffice Writer.

- Mark the option `Match case`
- Mark the option `Regular expressions`
- In the **Search:** field, insert the search term `[:upper:]` (searches for all uppercase letters)
- In the **Replace:** field, insert the term `,&` (which inserts a comma before each capital letter, the `&` ensures that the letter itself is not replaced
- Click "Replace All" button to finish

The result after replaced:

```
,Tenagomysis tasmaniae,Anisomysis mixta australis,Paramesopodopsis rufa,Cyathura carinata
```

Now copy all the text and paste into a spreadsheet document, e.g. LibreOffice Calc.

- Select the cell with the pasted text and select `Data > Text to columns ...`
- Mark the option `comma` as the separator and click "OK" button.
- Copy all text and do "Paste Special..." (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) and mark the option for `Transpose`.
- Click "OK" button to finish

The result after transposed:

```
Tenagomysis tasmaniae
Anisomysis mixta australis
Paramesopodopsis rufa
Cyathura carinata
```

Now you have every word string separated by a capital letter in one spreadsheet row.

Comment: +1 Tested working from my side. I have suggested edits to improve the answer. Feel free to reject or rollback if you didn't like.